# Why this C++ code is not counting properly?

Tags: c++

I have written a code in c++ to count zeros. The input have to take as string. The input will be a digit with 1 and 0.

**Example**:

Input: `1000000001`
Output: `8`

The answer should be 8 but my code is showing 0. Where is the problem in the code.

**Code**:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string players;
    cin >> players;
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < players.length(); j++)
    {
        if (players[j] == 0)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    cout << count;

    return 0;
}
```

Please help me to find and solve it.
Thank you.

Comment: Try using `players[j]=='0'`, as your check will check for the null terminator

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/5910058) / [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/5910058)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to compare with `char` not `int`:

```
if (players[j] == '0')
```

Answer (score 3):

`if` condition for `players[j] == 0` is wrong, your input is string type while you are trying to compare with the integer type 0. The correct `if` check is `players[j] == '0'`. Using `bits/stdc++.h` and `using namespace std;` is a big no in C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std:: string players;
    std:: cin >> players;
    int count = 0;
    for(const char &player : players)
    {
        if (player == '0')
        {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    std:: cout << count;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the condition is wrong.
write code like

```
players[j] == "0"
```

your condition means that

```
player[j] == NULL
```